# How to detect regression outliers when many residuals are zero

Tags: regression, outliers

I have a situation that when I fit a robust regression line (least trimmed squares) to a set of data a lot of the residuals are in fact zero.

This occurs mainly in the situation where the slope is zero and the y values are integers. When the line is fitted it runs right through the majority of the values. I am happy with this fit as a traditional least squares line is incorrect due to a few errors in the data.

However now I've fitted the line I want to analyze the residuals and detect the outliers (possibly automatically). I intended to compute a 'score' perhaps based on Tukey's technique of using the upper and lower quartile plus 1.5 times the inter-quartile range. However this approach won't work if many of the residuals are zero because the IQR is also zero.

What should I do? Just base the score on something like the number of standard deviations from the mean? Thanks.

Comment: What about the X values, are they all continuous?

Comment: @user603. The data are actually time series data (typically monthly), so I am exploring a couple of different approaches.

Comment: Is your data stationary? (e.g. first difference, or trend adjusted?)

Comment: @user603 No I haven't applied any differencing. In the data above 'time' is the independent variable. There are still other issues I'm exploring with the data, but I was curious about whether other people have encountered this situation also.

Comment: If your data is non stationnary, you might want to use the LTS-filter: it's the same approach as LTS, but as a filter. You will find more detail on page 23 of [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robfilter/robfilter.pdf) document.

Comment: @user603 Thanks that looks helpful I will check it out. By the way it may be the case that I need to write my own implementation of either a robust regression or LTS-filter. Putting performance issues aside (most of the series are relatively short perhaps 50 or so data points) are you aware of any books or papers that give a relatively straightforward explanation of how to implement the algorithm ? Thanks.

Comment: The book ("Robust Statistics: Theory and Methods") has a section on algorithms. But at the end of the day, there are so many details: most of these codes are open source and published under a licence that encourages re-use (the source of the R-code are in the package). Even if you on't plan to re-use you can look at the implementation and glean out the details.

Comment: @user603 Thanks I will check that book out. The LTS-filter solves my problem in many cases. However I'm still wondering whether there is some "rule of thumb" or statistical test that I could apply to the residuals to determine whether there is enough variability in them to allow some kind of analysis either with this data or other datasets. Thanks again.

Comment: @Antonia2100: they have variability, but on a lower dimensional manifold. The good data is like a 2D scatterplot in a 3D space. If you look at it in 2D, there is variability.

Answer (score 2):

Various thoughts:

1. You say that problem is mostly when the slope is zero. But whenever the regression is flat, the problem is the same as that of flagging univariate outliers for the response variable.
2. More generally, a sensible criterion may depend on the particular kind of robust regression you use, which you have now named as least trimmed squares.  (There are many flavours: few seem to sustain any popularity for more than a few years except for the oldest, L1 or more generally quantile regression.)
3. Why not just use the values of the residuals and plot them? Converting to residual/scale of residuals isn't always needed, even when you are using different response variables.
4. Much depends on quite why and how much you want or need to automate. If you are doing this hundreds, thousands… of times, then understood. If only a few times, you can waste more time worrying how best to do it than just looking at some plots. It's the transition between those situations that's tricky.

Comment: " few seem to sustain any popularity for more than a few years except for the oldest" which ones are you referring to?

Comment: The pattern of robust regression research seems to be that researchers favour their own methods, disparage others and nothing remains top of anyone's list for long. I've seen e.g. biweight and least median of squares pushed hard by proponents and then criticised strongly as often poor. I've seen more recent methods pushed hard only to learn that they are painfully slow or impracticable for large datasets. But I'm emphatically no expert and would welcome counterexamples of good methods that have lasted a decade in popularity and are recommended in _all_ monographs on robust statistics.

Comment: @Nick Cox Thanks for your reply. I added to my question that I used least trimmed squares. Yes plotting the residuals does work well, except I have potentially thousands of sets of data to work with that is why I hope to find an automated solution. In some cases the regression is flat, but not in all or even most cases. I wonder if I should look at using different methods depending on whether the regression is flat or not.

Comment: I think you need advice from someone very familiar with least trimmed squares.

Comment: @Antonio2100: LTS is regression equivariant (e.g. the outlyingness of an observation only depends on the residuals, not on the $\hat{\beta}$'s) so that the flatness of the regression line is immaterial to your problem.

Comment: *decade in popularity and are recommended in all monographs on robust statistics.* Even in theology, I doubt such a definition of consensus is tenable, let alone in science. Anyway, I'm pretty sure there is a consensus that L1 regression is not robust in the 'robust to outlier' sense of the word (and the consensus includes Koenker). Maybe you are more confused by the different definition of robustness in use? It's a word used to describe many different things (and it's more recent use in the context of outlier detection is a bit of an unhappy choice).

Comment: I think your comments support mine if you can't name one such method! In contrast much in mainstream statistics has been around for a century or two or more (means, least squares, etc.). I do include L1 regression under robust regression and am aware that robustness people have many different definitions of robustness; that's part of what makes the field confusing to others, not that the problems aren't very important and very difficult. Unfortunately the literature doesn't seem aimed at outsiders any more; that wasn't so true in the 1970s. Still, too much to discuss well in comments.

Comment: the mad (the first non trivial outlier robust estimator) was studied by Gauss, so that would be older than OLS. Robust in the sense of outlier-robust in more than one dimension is a combinatorial problem and so can only have been approached  in the early 80's. If you look at the early textbook on the subject (Robust Regression and Outlier Detection) and the latest one (Robust Statistics: Theory and Methods) they recommend the same approaches. There is more emphasize in the recent textbook on methods designed to improve efficiency at clean samples, but the basic  algorithms are the same.

Comment: and most of the important articles are published in *Technometrics* and *CSDA* so that makes them definitely geared towards practitioners. I'm not trying to convince you, just point out that your opinion may be prejudiced.

Comment: I was stating an impression, and do not have an expert opinion, as I said, and I am happy that you want to qualify or indeed to correct a throw-away remark, which is how this started. So, thanks for your remarks. Incidentally, least squares was introduced in 1805 or earlier, depending on whether you believe Gauss's priority claim, does predate MAD, which was 1816 if I recall correctly. I'd regard Boscovich as relevant here too.

Comment: @NickCox: thanks; I wrongly thought Gauss had explored the problem much earlier. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where many of the residuals were zero and the IQR would not be usable because it was either zero or close to zero. A practical solution I found worked reasonably was to use the interdecile range instead of the IQR. I then used the upper decile and lower decile and made the outer fences a multiple of the IDR away from these.